# Django contrib problems showing blank templates

Tags: django, admin

Im trying to deploy an application i made with Django on a Ubuntu 10 Server with mod_wsgi and Apache.

Everything seems to be all right, but, when i try to use the django admin nothing is showed. I inspect the html, and is a bank html :

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

I thought was only a admin problem, but i discovered it actually happends when i try to use the django.contrib auth login... so.. i tried a lot of thing, permissions, moving admin tempaltes... etc..

any ideas??

thank you a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure Apache can find the directory where the admin static media is located? I recall having a similar problem in the past, and solved it by creating a symbolic link for it inside my `media` directory:

```
mgibsonbr@***(~/***/media)$ ls -l
total 4K
lrwxr-xr-x 1 mgibsonbr users  87 Nov 18 14:29 admin -> /home/mgibsonbr/***/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media
```

My httpd.conf:

```
DocumentRoot /home/mgibsonbr/www/***
Alias /media/ /home/mgibsonbr/www/***/media/

WSGIDaemonProcess *** user=mgibsonbr group=users threads=5
WSGIProcessGroup ***
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/mgibsonbr/www/***.wsgi
```

And my Django settings.py:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/admin/'
```

Note: some parts anonymized

If you haven't done any programming mistakes, maybe you could ask this question in [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com), they'll probably be able to better help you there.

Comment: i tried this on a apache server on Windows on my pc, and every thing is allright.. so i assume is not a programming error. I dont believe the issue is caussed by media problem, cauz the response comes without any content... I think if the only problem is the media of admin... i should can watch the styless login at least... its correct?

And, other think i found is, any response except HttpResponse o render_to_response generate this almost blank html

Comment: @user1137897 You're right about the styless login. About the rest, that's beyond my knowledge, but if I were debugging it I'd look: is the `/admin` really running a view? the right view? is `/media/admin` really loading a static page? are static pages in general running fine? Sorry I couldn't help more.